# Write a function join which, given two lists, it returns a list in which each element is a list of two elements, one from each of the given lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I reach the following goal??

Write a function join which, given two `lists`, it returns a `list` in which each element is a `list`
of two elements, one from each of the given `lists`. For example:

```
join( [1,2,3] , [”a”,”b”,”c”] )
```

returns

```
[ [1,”a”], [2,”b”], [3,”c”] ]
```

assume that the given lists both have the same length

Comment: @Coldspeed it isn't. He's asking for it to be turned into a list of LISTS.

Comment: If both list have same length you can use `list comprehension` as well `[[list1[index], list2[index]] for index in range(len(list1))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use zip:

```
def join(a, b):
    return [[i, c] for i, c in zip(a, b)]

print join([1,2,3], ['a','b','c'])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]
```

Comment: What's with those quotes? You have a syntax error in the function body, too.

Comment: opps, sorry, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***zip***:

```
def join(list_a, list_b):
    return [list(tup) for tup in zip(list_a, list_b)]



a = [1,2,3]
b = ["a", "b", "c"]
c = join(a, b)
print c #prints [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]]
```

Comment: What's wrong with the answer please? Let me know it is important.